# Manager ignores workplace violence

Tags: human-resources

Yesterday, I witnessed a very violent physical fight at work.  It was between two grown men, both peers on my team.

Basically, one guy walked up and criticized another guy's work.  Shouting ensued, and then somebody grabbed the other's laptop.  They wrestled over the laptop for a minute.  When one guy grabbed it free, he swung it hard and hit the other over the head with the laptop.

The blow was so hard, it made an audible "crunch" sound.  The laptop was destroyed and pieces of it were scattered on the floor.  The two of them were then quickly split up by others (including me).  The guy who got hit seemed dazed.  Might have had a concussion, but I don't know.

I was obviously stunned by the whole incident.  I was equally shocked when both men came into work the next day.  I thought for sure they'd be fired.

I talked to my manager and asked what was going to happen to them.  He said probably nothing, and tried to convince me that it wasn't a big deal and "boys will be boys".  I asked what HR did in these circumstances, and he said he generally only gets HR involved when there's a real problem.  When I showed concern, he told me he'd deal with the situation.

His way of dealing with it was to send out a politely worded e-mail that basically said "Please no hitting people over the head with laptops".  I asked both of the two coworkers involved in the fight if my manager talked with them, and they both said "No, why?".

It's not that I want to get these two coworkers fired, but I really don't think my manager is taking this seriously.  Is it appropriate to go over his head and try to talk with his boss about this?  Or maybe HR?  Or should I just assume he's got things under control?

Comment: Location is important here, perfectly acceptable behaviour in many places except the laptop might need to be paid for. Aggravated assault in other places. Also reason for the fight is important.

Comment: What is your problem? You want to be in the next fight and be fired? If your manager is finding a way to keep two valuable members on his team, why are you wanting to derail that? Dead men’s shoes?

Comment: Keep quiet. Update your resume. Find a job in a company which doesn't include the risk of serious head injury

Comment: Well it's strange that this seems normal based upon all these comments. I don't have a lot of experience as a H1B worker, I would assume it would be like home.

Comment: @5DollarKFCMeal location is important as previously mentioned. As you didn't provide it, and no one got arrested, I guess the assumption is that you live in a country where things like that are relative norm.

Comment: If something like this happens to you personally. Call the police. That's what I would do.

Comment: Why would the individual who got hit with their laptop be fired?  They were assaulted.

Comment: @SolarMike and what if someone else’s fight ended up with you in hospital, because the laptop slipped out of someone’s hands during the swing and struck you instead?  Workplace violence should never ever be tolerated.

Comment: @Donald some "zero tolerance" policies (usually those in schools) are written such that _everyone_ involved in an altercation to any degree is punished, and usually the same punishment is applied to all.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul OP mentioned H1B so it's the US.

Comment: Why make such a drama about one broken laptop and a possible cerebral hematoma? Me and my colleague destroy about five laptops per project in fights over naming-conventions for global variables. Jokes aside and on a serious note - A blow with a laptop on the head might end fatal if unlucky..

Comment: Sort of a nitpick but unless the laptop was made in the early 90s it isn't going to do any significant damage to anyone, short of possibly minor cuts.  Also I think the industry is important here as well as the location.  In an office environment this probably should never be accepted but in a mechanics shop or construction site (unlikely to have a laptop) this would probably be something regularly brushed off.

Answer (score 9):

## Go to HR. Tell them you feel unsafe, and why.

HR is not your friend; HR’s job is to protect the company from liability, and the company would likely be liable for any injuries gained from violent actions taken in the workplace by employees. Naturally, HR would want to minimise the number of workers’ compensation claims, and that would mean that they would want to minimise the amount of violence in the workplace.

Depending on location, there may also be forms that need to be filled out- in Australia, for instance, employers are required under the Workplace Health and Safety regulations to fill out Incident Report forms whenever there’s an incident in the workplace that may have resulted in injuries. If this is the case in your location, HR would know about it.

Comment: I can’t speak for OP but even if I wasn’t involved in the altercation, *I* certainly would feel unsafe knowing that I shared a workplace with  a volatile individual who resorts to physical assault and destruction of company property in response to what might be a valid criticism.

Comment: @alroc or could be a response to something he said about the chaps daughter, or pretty much anything

Comment: @Kilisi it doesn’t matter. Assaulting another person in the workplace is not acceptable. If HR isn’t going to address it, the police should.

Comment: @alroc if you wouldn't defend your daughters honour... then I don't know what to say to that. Police respond to complaints, neither of the offenders are making one.

Comment: @Kilisi now you're putting words into peoples' mouths and making some _very_ large assumptions and accusations. If you resort to physical violence to the point where a laptop computer is broken over the head of another human being because of _words_, you have issues and need to be removed from that environment.

Comment: @alroc noI'm not, I gave an example, you said the example didn't matter.... pretty simple, no sense wriggling around. It was straightforwards. I've seen lots of fight, been in several as well.... mostly blue collar days, but it's reasonably common here in offices as well... so location makes a difference. Foreigner complaining would be removed from their job.

Answer (score 5):

I've managed teams for many years and I've observed several major confrontations, arguments etc and whilst I'll concede that letting some conflict pass can be a release, to me physical violence crosses a clear line.

H1B visa implies you're a foreign worker in the USA (feel free to correct me if wrong) and I know employment laws and norms differ from country to country but in NZ you'd almost certainly be fired on the spot for physical violence.

This is where your question gets a little tricky in my view. If you want to raise it further then (rights and wrongs aside)  an inevitable consequence might be that one or both or your coworkers gets fired.

If something like this happened at my place of work and it wasn't taken seriously then I'd probably be looking elsewhere for work. The H1B visa could be a complicating factor though because the visa might be tied to my employer.

Obviously there are a range of views and I respect that but my view is that no-one should have to put up with violence in the workplace.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not that I want to get these two coworkers fired.

Then mind your own business and trust that the hierarchy has things under control. All your information after the event is third hand. They may have been told not to talk about it, you have no way of knowing.

Or you may be able to push hard enough to get people sacked and your manager in trouble. Then with nothing to lose someone gives you a broken jaw on their way out. Or everyone denies anything happened. Either way it's going to taint your rep with the people you have to work with every day.

If you're a foreigner there on a visa, don't get involved in anything that makes you enemies.

Comment: I would add "start looking for a new job yesterday"

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I've seen plenty of much worse fistfights at work, never thought of leaving a job over it.

Comment: Normally your "cover your own arse and ignore the rest" approach is quite popular, but not in this situation. I guess there is a point where it can become too self-centric

Comment: @ig-dev this is a fairly popular answer, only 5 downvotes, not too bad, nowhere near my unpopular answers yet.

Comment: @ig-dev yep all the way until the foreigner finds his visa disappearing and no income and heads home with a black eye, with nothing accomplished... I'm not anti conflict at all, I'm anti-risking revenue stream over trivialities and long term rep damage. Yet if the situation warranted it I'd wade in swinging with no hesitation. Potential consequences far outweigh any positives here, I don't even see any positives. Get 2 people sacked and your manager in trouble? Two families plunged into a struggle to feed their kids with no income?

Comment: I agree with turning a blind eye as long as that's ethical. Only if I felt morally compelled to do something, then I'd accept collateral damage on my behalf. In OP's case, I really don't make it my business how much they beat each other over the head as long as it's between them alone - nothing to achieve, not my place morally or professionally. So (not that it matters) I agree with your approach here, despite my previous comment.

Comment: @ig-dev you put it very well, my English isn't the best, but 'collateral damage on my behalf' is an excellent way of looking at things. A viewpoint often lacking in many answers on this site.... no idea why....Unemployment can lead to destroyed families, alcohol/drug abuse, self harm, even death. I'm old, seen it all happen.